# Android: Unable to restart an ListActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

First post, so please go easy.

I have an app with a handful of tabs, the first is opened on running the app.
One of the tabs is 'My Account' (a ListActivity) showing account options. I switch to this and if the user is not logged in, it, in turn, runs a UserLogon activity using the following:

```
Intent logonActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UserLogon.class);
startActivityForResult(logonActivity, 0);
```

To catch the result, I use the following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0){
        MainBlock ta = (MainBlock) this.getParent();
        TabHost th = ta.getMyTabHost();
        th.setCurrentTab(0);
        finish();
    }
    if (requestCode == 100)
    {
        showAccountOptions();
    }
}
```

In the UserLogon class, I have the usual fare; TextView's and Button's. The intention is that if the user cancels the login, it will revert to the initial tab, or if login is successful, it will show the Account Options. And this is indeed what does happen.

All good so far.

The problem I'm having is that if I cancel the login and return to the first tab, when I select the Accounts tab again, I'm not presented with the UserLogon activity. I was under the impression that `finish()` would close the UserLogon activity, and the Accounts activity but it would appear not.

So, my question is simply, how do I, in effect, restart the Accounts activity so that the user would be presented with the option to login once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're good people and all willing to help ;-) I'll give it a shot. Still, I'm not quite sure I get that all right.

Basically you have an TabActivity which you setup and where you do something like that:

```
myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if (tabId.equals("account") && !loggedIn) {
        Intent logonActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UserLogon.class);
        startActivityForResult(logonActivity, 0);
    }
}});
```

You're basically saying that the first Activity start of UserLogon works, but the second one doesn't, right? Did you debugged to that point to check whether you reach the code which starts the activity again?

**Update based on comment**

Your `UserLogon` should always provide a result information, here's a blueprint:

```
public class UserLogon extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // ... do something ...

        // if activity is canceled this will be the "last" result
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }

    public void checkLoginOrSomethingLikeThat() {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        // put your results in this intent
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        // close activity since we have the information we need
        finish();
    }
}
```

The parent activity which is waiting for the result should do it like that:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // it's good practice to use a constant for 0 like LOGIN_REQUEST
    // otherwise you will ask yourself later "What the hell did 0 stand for?"
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // get needed data from data intent and react on that
        } else {
            // no success, react on that
        }
    }

    // ... I don't know what your resultCode 100 is but handle itwith the same pattern
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the swift reply, it's gotten me nearer to my goal.

I've now added the setOnTabChangedListener and it now fires the UserLogon activity when I select the Account tab. However, on click of the Cancel button, I'm presented with the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.app.myApp/com.app.myApp.MainBlock}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Any ideas?

Comment: To add, my MainBlock also has OnActivityResult and the UserLogon activity calls setResult.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see the idea how to use a result of an activity. Maybe this will help you to figure out what's going wrong.